# Connect Jira to Postgresql with Pgpool-II

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I gotta problem with connecting Jira 6 to Pgpool-II which is responsible for load balancing and  replication in Postgresql bases(2 instances).

[image]

Pgpool is started on port 9999, I just want to connect to it in this (Jira)installation step but Jira tolds that connection attempt failed....

Comment: What's the `...`? Connection attempt failed because ... [error detail here please]

Comment: "Error connecting to database"

Pgpool configuration of nodes:
backend_hostname0 = 'localhost'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_hostname1 = 'localhost'
backend_port1 = 5433
backend_weight1 = 1

Comment: Wow. That's a spectacularly unhelpful error. I'd check the container/appserver logs for the real stack trace.

Comment: Situation: there are two postgresql servers on ports 5433, 5434. Pgpool is started on port 9999, bases has no passwords set so access is easy(for testing)

Comment: Well ... check the pgpool logs and your servlet container logs. I'd also try `psql 'host=localhost port=9999 dbname=postgres username=postgres password=whatever'`.

Comment: option with psql checked, configuration of pgpool is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... check the pgpool logs and your servlet container logs.

I'd also try `psql 'host=localhost port=9999 dbname=postgres username=postgres password=whatever'`

Most likely the PgPool configuration has issues. If it works from `psql`, you'd need to check out the server logs to see what's up.

Comment: ok now I can login from console level, but during Jira installation process still cannot proceed, anyway I know where to look for the problem Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Jira and Confluence have some issues starting up with PGPool -> PostgreSQL IF you have read-only query load balancing turned on in PGPool.  Turn it off, then see if you can get Jira to successfully connect several times.  Then, turn it back on and catch the errors...either Hibernate, C3P0, and/or PGPool get confused and some queries try to get bounced off the standby that should NOT be routed to the standby.  Grab those errors and open a PGPool bug report with them...PGPool should handle Jira and Confluence just fine with load balancing turned on, but it does not (at least not in the versions I've tried).

OR, you could turn load balancing off, startup Jira, then turn load balancing back on.  It only impacts Jira on startup, not during normal operation.  That'll at least get you going.  But definitely report whatever errors you see so the PGPool guys can fix it!